# WPF Data Templates Equivalent in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: wpf, asp.net-mvc

WPF provides the ability to create data templates.  These templates can be used to render objects of certain types. I have a list of objects within a hierarchy, that I wish to display in a view.  An example of a single WPF data template is shown below.  This renders the following control, containing a label and text box, when an object of type FreeTextQuestion is part of the model to be rendered onto the view.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type QuestionTypes:FreeTextQuestion}">
    <StackPanel x:Name="FieldTextQuestion">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200px"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20px"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label x:Name="label" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource questionTitle}" />
            <TextBox x:Name="textbox" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource standardTextBox}" src:FocusExtension.IsFocused="{Binding Path=IsFocused, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="Value" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <DataErrorValidationRule/>
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

My question is how could I achieve this same thing in ASP.NET MVC?  Is there such an Equivalent?  Can this be achieved using Html Helper Extensions and/or user controls?  There are dependencies, for example I might have a group box control which is the parent of the free text question control shown above, so some templates would contain a list of other templates, etc.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: I want to do basically the same, so how did you solve this in MVC?

Answer (score 0):

The only way of doing that (that I know of) is using a strongly-typed [partial view](http://rachelappel.com/razor/partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-w-the-razor-view-engine/).

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent is a ViewModel with DataAnnotation attributes.

Basically, instead of an XML document you create a class, and decorate the properties with attributes to specify the template and formatting information, and the validation constraints.

rsenna is correct that the representation of this model is through a strongly typed partial view, but the actual definition will occur in the view model class.

You will want to look into the `ModelMetadata`, `ModelMetadataProvider`, and `ModelValidator` classes as well as their implemented derivatives and uses to get a full understanding of how this works.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalents are editor and display templates, which are partial views placed in specially-named folders.

You can use `@Html.DisplayFor()` or `@Html.EditorFor()` to invoke these templates. The appropriate template will be picked based on the value you pass.

If no template exists, MVC will auto-generate one for you. As smartcaveman says, you can use data annotations to control to some extent what it auto-generates.

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html